# How to trim a string in a yajra datatable used a raw query in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, datatable, eloquent, yajra-datatable

I have a problem on how to trim string in my datatable from a query where in used a raw query to get data from the database.

my query example is

```
public function data()
    {
        return DB::table('query_table')
            ->select([
                DB::raw('query_table.data1 AS data1'),
                DB::raw('query_table2.data2 AS data2'),
            ])
            ->join('query_table2','query_table2.query_table_id','=','query_table.id')
            ->where(['query_table.id' => 1])
            ->orderByDesc('query_table.data1')
            ->get();
    }
```

from controller for my data table

```
public function dataDataTable()
    {
        $data = $this->query->data(); //query of data

        return DataTables::of($data)
            ->addIndexColumn()
            ->make(true);
    }
```

I am using datatables as view in laravel

```
@extends('layouts.main' , ['title' => trans('label.data.table')])

    @include('includes.datatable_assets')

    @push('after-styles')

        @include('includes.custom_assets')
    @endpush
    @section('content')
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <header class="card-header card-header-custom">
                    <h2 class="card-title" style="color: white" >{!! trans('label.table.header') !!}</h2>
                </header>
                <div class="" id="list-all">
                    <table class="display" id="templates-table">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>@lang('label.sn')</th>
                            <th>@lang('label.data1')</th>
                            <th>@lang('label.data2')</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endsection

    @push('after-scripts')

        <script  type="text/javascript">

            $('#templates-table').DataTable({
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,

                ajax: '{!! route('query.datatable.route') !!}',
                type: 'get',
                columns: [
                    {data: 'DT_RowIndex', name: 'DT_RowIndex', orderable: false, searchable: false, width: '5%'},
                    {data: 'data1', name: 'data1', orderable: false, searchable: true, width: '65%'},
                    {data: 'data2', name: 'data2', orderable: false, searchable: true, width: '35%'},      
                ],
        </script>

    @endpush
```

How do I trim data1 string so as can be seen with few characters in my datatable view ?

Comment: Could you add an example of the current string and what your desired result is.

Comment: my current string holds more than 100 characters because is a description provided from user input and information suppose to be shown on the datatable view few characters about 50 characters from the store description in the database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either do it in PHP or in Javascript:

**Javascript:**

```
$('#templates-table').DataTable({
    ...,
    columnDefs: [{
        targets: 1,
        render: function (data, type, row) {
            return type === 'display' && data.length > 50 ? data.substr(0, 50) + '…' : data;
        }
    }]
});
```

You can read more about it [here](https://datatables.net/blog/2016-02-26).

**PHP:**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

public function dataDataTable()
{
    $data = $this->query->data(); // query of data

    return DataTables::of($data)
        ->editColumn('data1', function ($data) {
            return Str::limit($data->data1, 50);
        })
        ->addIndexColumn()
        ->make(true);
}
```

If you don't have to show the user the full string I would use the PHP version, so your response does not get bloated.